# Set Frame size of CollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

I have made a semi rounded `collectionView`. I want to set my `collectionView` frame that take only half of screen but it take Full screen so I am unable to do any things.

Please let me know how to set frame for that `UICollectionView`.

```
DSCircularLayout *circularLayout = [[DSCircularLayout alloc] init];
    [circularLayout initWithCentre:CGPointMake(SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT)
                            radius:165
                          itemSize:CGSizeMake(ITEM_WIDTH, ITEM_HEIGHT)
                 andAngularSpacing:60];

    [circularLayout setStartAngle:M_PI endAngle:0];
    circularLayout.mirrorX = NO;
    circularLayout.mirrorY = NO;
    circularLayout.rotateItems = YES;

    circularLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollPositionRight;
  //  self.menuCollection.init(f: CGRect, collectionViewLayout layout: UICollectionViewLayout);

    [self.menuCollection setCollectionViewLayout:circularLayout];
```

menuCollection is my `collectionView` which i want to set frame.

thanks

Comment: What is the View controller where `menuCollection` is used? UIViewController or something else?

Comment: I strongly recommend not to set frames by yourself. It is much more convenient and flexible to use [auto layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/)!

Comment: @ladislav it is uiviewcontroller

Comment: @reinhardManner I am okiey with Autolayout but want to give only half screen i try to do it using storyboards then my semicircle disappear

Comment: Add a screenshot of the storyboard where your collection view is with collection view selected or code if it is added in code...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are not using auto-layout, and your collection view's parent view is full screen size, you can set it as follows.

```
CGFloat size = self.menuCollection.superview.bounds.size;
self.menuCollection.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, size.height / 4, size.width, size.height / 2);
```